# Occasional ACCESS_VIOLATION error while calling MmProbeAndLockPages for usermode process memory

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-management, kernel

So, I'm trying to lock the pages of a user-mode process memory using the mix of IoAllocateMdl and MmProbeAndLockPages. This is what my code for the locking looks like :

```c
PEPROCESS TargetProcess = ... // Target process's EPROCESS
PVOID virtual_adddress = ... // Target address
SIZE_T size = ... // Target size
KAPC_STATE pApcState = NULL;
PMDL pMDL = NULL;
KPROCESSOR_MODE access_mode = KernelMode;
LOCK_OPERATION operation = IoModifyAccess;

KeStackAttachProcess(TargetProcess, &pApcState);

try {
    mdl = IoAllocateMdl(PAGE_ALIGN(virtual_address), ADDRESS_AND_SIZE_TO_SPAN_PAGES(PAGE_ALIGN(virtual_address), size) << PAGE_SHIFT, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    MmProbeAndLockPages(mdl, access_mode, operation);
}except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "LockPages - Failed! VA : %p, Exception : %p", PAGE_ALIGN(virtual_address), GetExceptionCode());
        
    if (mdl) IoFreeMdl(mdl);
    KeUnstackDetachProcess(&pApcState);
        
    return;
}
```

and of course, I didn't forget to clean up (MmUnlockPages, IoFreeMdl) after I did my stuff.
So the error here is only occasional, so sometimes there is no error, but sometimes it appears. The memory I'm trying to lock is a memory allocated using VirtualAlloc with MEM_COMMIT and MEM_RESERVE. Anybody know why the error appears?

Comment: Is this your actual code? I'm not familiar with a programming language where `try {} except(...)` is legal.

Comment: @IInspectable [WDK macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/handling-exceptions) around `__try` and `__except`.